# How to share variables across instances?

Tags: ansible, testing, python, molecule

I'm writing [TestInfra](https://testinfra.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) test scripts for mongo cluster instances using [Molecule](https://molecule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) [Ansible](https://www.ansible.com/). I want to share variables across all the instances. I created a python class, and initialise and update the variables. Every time `molecule verify`, each test will run on each instance, so variables are independent on single instance.

How can I share variables across instances?

Answer (score 3):

Q: ***"Is it possible to share variables across instances?"***

A: Yes. The dictionary *hostvars* keeps the variables. *hostvars* lets you access variables for another host, including facts that have been gathered about that host. You can access host variables at any point in a playbook. For example,

```yaml
{{ hostvars['test.example.com']['ansible_facts']['distribution'] }}
```

See:

- [Information about Ansible: magic variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_vars_facts.html#information-about-ansible-magic-variables)
- [Scoping variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#scoping-variables)
- [Cache plugins](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/cache.html#cache-plugins)

---

With “Fact Caching” disabled, to share information among Ansible playbooks, it's possible to store all *hostvars* in a file. For example, given the inventory

```ini
shell> cat hosts
[test]
test_01
test_02
test_03
```

this template

```yaml
shell> cat my_hostvars.json.j2
my_hostvars_all:
{% for my_host in ansible_play_hosts_all %}
  {{ my_host }}:
    {{ hostvars[my_host]|to_nice_json }}
{% endfor %}
```

and the playbook below

```yaml
shell> cat pb1.yml 
- hosts: test

  tasks:

    - set_fact:
        test_var: "test_var_in_{{ inventory_hostname }}"

    - template:
        src: my_hostvars.json.j2
        dest: "{{ playbook_dir }}/my_hostvars.json"
      delegate_to: localhost
      run_once: true
```

store *hostvars* of all hosts into the dictionary
*my_hostvars_all* and put it into the file

```yaml
{{ playbook_dir }}/my_hostvars.json
```

at localhost(master). The dictionary can be included in the next playbook. For example, the playbook

```yaml
shell> cat pb2.yml
- hosts: test

  tasks:

    - include_vars: my_hostvars.json

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ my_hostvars_all[inventory_hostname]['test_var'] }}"
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
ok: [test_01] => 
  msg: test_var_in_test_01
ok: [test_02] => 
  msg: test_var_in_test_02
ok: [test_03] => 
  msg: test_var_in_test_03
```